# Looking for a graphic tool to visually present testing coverage

Tags: tools, javascript, test-coverage

I have been reviewing existing test cases.

There is no easy way to visualise current testing coverage; the only way testing coverage can be assessed is reading through the test case repository, e.g.

[image]

- It is very time consuming and inefficient.

I am wondering if there is any automated tool that can present test cases in a graphic manner, e.g.

[image]

- Each box / button represent a test suite, which we can click into to see all the test cases in this suite, e.g.

[image]

The language is JavaScript, testing framework is Jasmine.

Comment: Nice handwriting.

Comment: @user246, thanks. I try my best. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really?  My testrail does that just fine, and automatically. With several kinds of graphs at most levels.

Comment: I will take a look.

Comment: Not easy to google without falling into a pit of real trains :-).  Try http://www.gurock.com/testrail/